# docker-maven-plugin with MongoDB image hangs on startup

Tags: mongodb, maven, docker, maven-docker-plugin

I'm trying to configure MongoDB image with docker-maven-plugin.

This is my configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
    <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.21.0</version>

    <configuration>
        <showLogs>true</showLogs>

        <images>
            <image>
                <name>mongo:3.0.15</name>
                <alias>mongo</alias>
                <run>
                    <ports>
                        <port>27017:27017</port>
                    </ports>
                    <wait>
                        <log>waiting for connections on port</log>
                        <time>60000</time>
                    </wait>
                </run>
            </image>
        </images>
    </configuration>

    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>prepare-containers</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>start</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>remove-containers</id>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>stop</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

When I invoke

mvn docker:start -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

the invocation hangs with the following output:

```
D:\Projects\decisionwanted\domain>mvn docker:start -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building domain 0.0.1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- docker-maven-plugin:0.21.0:start (default-cli) @ domain ---
[INFO] DOCKER> [mongo:3.0.15] "mongo": Start container af3368374f17
mongo> 2017-07-27T07:48:55.621+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=af3368374f17
mongo> 2017-07-27T07:48:55.621+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.0.15
mongo> 2017-07-27T07:48:55.621+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: b8ff507269c382bc100fc52f75f48d54cd42ec3b
mongo> 2017-07-27T07:48:55.621+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build info: Linux ip-10-166-66-3 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.46-1 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
mongo> 2017-07-27T07:48:55.621+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
mongo> 2017-07-27T07:48:55.621+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
mongo> 2017-07-27T07:48:55.637+0000 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] journal dir=/data/db/journal
mongo> 2017-07-27T07:48:55.638+0000 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
mongo> 2017-07-27T07:48:55.783+0000 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] preallocateIsFaster=true 2.54
mongo> 2017-07-27T07:48:55.824+0000 I JOURNAL  [durability] Durability thread started
mongo> 2017-07-27T07:48:55.824+0000 I JOURNAL  [journal writer] Journal writer thread started
mongo> 2017-07-27T07:48:55.829+0000 I INDEX    [initandlisten] allocating new ns file /data/db/local.ns, filling with zeroes...
mongo> 2017-07-27T07:48:55.874+0000 I STORAGE  [FileAllocator] allocating new datafile /data/db/local.0, filling with zeroes...
mongo> 2017-07-27T07:48:55.874+0000 I STORAGE  [FileAllocator] creating directory /data/db/_tmp
mongo> 2017-07-27T07:48:55.875+0000 I STORAGE  [FileAllocator] done allocating datafile /data/db/local.0, size: 64MB,  took 0 secs
mongo> 2017-07-27T07:48:55.878+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
```

How to properly configure MongoDB image with docker-maven-plugin ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following configuration works fine:

```
                <image>
                    <name>mongo:3.4.6</name>
                    <alias>mongo</alias>
                    <run>
                        <ports>
                            <port>${mongodb.port}:27017</port>
                        </ports>
                        <env>
                        <MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME>${mongodb.username}</MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME>
                        <MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD>${mongodb.password}</MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD>

                        </env>
                        <wait>
                            <log>waiting for connections on port</log>
                            <time>60000</time>
                        </wait>
                    </run>
                </image>
```